# How do I check if a permission is set to neutral ("/") with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to check if a channel override is set to neutral/null/"/". I know how to *set* a permission to neutral, but not how to check if it is in that state. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a helper function that checks the `permissionOverwrites` in a channel. `channel.permissionOverwrites` returns a collection of [`permissionOverwrites`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/PermissionOverwrites).

1. If the `size` of the collection is zero, you know that everything is in neutral position. If there is at least one permission allowed or denied for the `@everyone` role, the collection size won't be zero.
2. If there is at least one element in the collection, you can check their [`allow`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/PermissionOverwrites?scrollTo=allow) and [`deny`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/PermissionOverwrites?scrollTo=deny) properties. If their [`bitfield`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=bitfield) property is larger than zero, it is not set to neutral.

Collections have an [`.every()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=every) method that checks if every element in the collection passes the test implemented in the callback function. If both the `allow` and `deny` props `bitfield` is `0`, you know that it's set to neutral.

Check the function below:

```js
function isNeutral({ channel }) {
  const { permissionOverwrites } = channel;

  if (permissionOverwrites.size === 0) return true;

  return permissionOverwrites.every(
    (perm) => perm.allow.bitfield === 0 && perm.deny.bitfield === 0,
  );
}
```

If you only want to check a single overwrite in a channel, you can update the function like this:

```js
function isNeutral({ channel, overwriteID = null }) {
  const { permissionOverwrites } = channel;

  if (permissionOverwrites.size === 0) return true;

  if (overwriteID) {
    const perm = permissionOverwrites.get(overwriteID);
    if (!perm) {
      throw new Error(
        `No permission overwrite found with the role ID or user ID of "${overwriteID}" in this channel.`,
      );
    }
    return perm.allow.bitfield === 0 && perm.deny.bitfield === 0;
  }

  return permissionOverwrites.every(
    (perm) => perm.allow.bitfield === 0 && perm.deny.bitfield === 0,
  );
}
```

And this is how you can use it inside your event handlers:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  try {
    const neutral = isNeutral({
      channel: message.channel,
    });

    console.log(`All of the permission overwrites are set to neutral: ${neutral}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```